# How to configure JSS application to make it Visible in "Sites" section in XM Cloud

Tags: xm-cloud

We have a `JSS` application deployed to `XM Cloud` portal (community).

[image]

From Portal Dashboard when I go to `Pages` I am able to see the site preview as well.

[image]

But when I go to `Sites` tab, it says no sites created yet.

[image]

Because of this, I am unable to personalize anything. What are the steps to make my existing JSS application visible in the Sites tab?

Answer (score 0):

Select the "Sites" tab in the menu on the left.

Find and click the button labeled "**Register Site**".

Input the necessary information in the "**Register Site**" window, including the site name, URL, and description.

In the "**Site configuration**" section, choose "**Sitecore JavaScript Services**" as the site type.

Provide the JSS application name in the "**JSS App Name**" field.

Enter the hostname of the JSS application in the "**JSS App Host Name**" field.

Click on the button to register the JSS application as a site on the XM Cloud portal.

Answer (score 0):

For Personalize to work, you need to create a `site identifier` and assign it to your website in the XM Cloud Dashboard Settings.

Steps to create a site identifier:

1. Access your environment's Dashboard.
2. In the Dashboard, click `Settings`.

   Alternatively, in the Dashboard, click `Sites`, and for the website of your choice, click the `Action` menu to access the `site-specific settings`.
3. Click `Create new`.
4. In the `Create new site identifier` dialog, enter a name for the identifier, such as the website address.
5. In the drop-down list, click the `language` of the website that needs a site identifier.
6. Optionally, enter the `market` and `brand` that describe the website best. For example, you could have a global website for brand X, or a Scandinavian website for brand Z.
7. Click the up and down arrows from the `Timeout` field to indicate after how many minutes you want a browser session to time out as a result of inactivity. This time is set at 30 minutes by default, and it will not affect how Analyze and Personalize work in XM Cloud Pages.
8. Click `Save`.

In the Dashboard Settings tab, the site identifier is now listed in the table and can be assigned to a website from your environment.

If you have created the identifier directly in the website-specific settings, it is assigned automatically to the website in the language selected.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue you're facing with the Sites tab indicating "no sites created yet" in the XM Cloud portal is likely due to the absence of a Headless Site collection (Headless tenant) and the associated headless site.

Ensure that you have created a Headless Site Collection using the OOTB option provided in XM Cloud. It seems from the provided information that the template used for creating the tenant might not be correct. Follow this documentation to see right way to create a website in XM Cloud.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/users/xm-cloud/create-websites.html

Once you have successfully created the headless site collection and associated headless site, make sure to create a site identifier and assign it to the website.